# CentOS httpd downloading pages instead of parsing them

Tags: apache-2.2, php, httpd

Okay maybe this question has been asked before, I couldn't find the solution I searched both StackOverflow and Serverfault.

Fist of all I'm running
`CentOS release 5.5 (Final)`

I had by default `PHP 5.1.6` and HTTPD (`Apache/2.2.3`)

Now I had to upgrade `PHP 5.1.6` to `PHP 5.3` to enable zip support.

I ran a few yum commands such as.

`yum remove php php-*`

Then I ran

`yum install php53 php53-cli php53-devel php53-gd  php53-mbstring php53-mysql php53-pdo php53-xml php53-xmlrpc php-pear`

After the installation was a success.

I ran
`service httpd restart`

`service httpd reload`

And now when I go to `MyDomain.com` it downloads the PHP page as plain-text.
Now if I go to `www.MyDomain.com` it parses the page properly.

Can someone tell me whats wrong?

Man I screwed up big time.

My `httpd.conf` file is below how it was when PHP 5.1.6 was and it worked properly with that PHP 5.1.6.

http://pastebin.com/tES5k85V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` is still present and being included. It's provided by the both the `php` and `php53` packages, so it should be present. You may have a `php.conf.rpmsave` in that directory that you can move into place as well.

Comment: Yes I have in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`  `php.conf` file,  what must I do to fix this? thanks, how do I include it? Btw as you know.. it actually parses PHP.. when you put www.Domain.com without www just Domain.com it downloads the PHP file..

Comment: Ah, I missed that, sorry. I can't immediately think of what would cause a problem there, then. Do you have separate VirtualHosts for those domains? (Can you supply the output of `httpd -S`?)

Comment: VirtualHost configuration:
174.122.112.38:80      26.70.7aae.static.theplanet.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1001)
Syntax OK, And Yes I do have 2 VirtualHosts for 2 websites. look at http://pastebin.com/tES5k85V (very bottom). I own X.X.X.37 and X.X.X.38 both ran by same httpd apache.

Comment: BTW.. I just cleared my cache and history from Google Chrome.. and when I visit now.. `www.MyDomain.com` and `MyDomain.com` and `MyDomain.com/index.php` and `www.MyDomain.com/index.php` it actually visits the site in all cases parsing the PHP properly.. BUT before the google cache was cleared.. everytime I would go.. it would download the PHP source codes. Even if it was just a cache problem.. Seems I have a security problem now.. It always downloaded the source code before I cleared the cache, unless it just downloaded from the cache.. but i will never be sure now.. :(

Comment: Last thing I can think of: you have a couple `AddType`s on lines 769 and 770 that are probably messing with the `AddType` included from `conf.d/php.conf` Try commenting them out.

Comment: Well it seems to have been fixed.. magically.. probably was pending the changes somewhere and finally finished. Blah I rather not touch it from this point on it's working atleast.. I start having doubts like.. I know conf.d is loaded with httpd.. but is php.conf loaded? or not? or maybe randomly loaded.. I haven't found any trace of php.conf in conf.d.. but then again conf.d folder probably loads everything inside there.. then again where do I see error logs? or loading logs? something to be sure everything loaded? Other then that seems solved.. Thanks alot Josh.

Comment: The `Include conf.d/*.conf` line dumps every file matching that pattern into the file at that point. As noted on lines 25-30, that path is relative to the `ServerRoot`, which is `/etc/httpd` on your system. The `ErrorLog` directive works similarly; on RHEL-based systems `/etc/httpd/logs` is a symlink to `/var/log/httpd`, so you'll find the error log in there.

Comment: BTW - dont` forget to add "RemoveType .php" statements for (sub)directories where users can upload files. Else they can upload php code and execute that on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)?  If not you may want to start over and try again (remove php53-*).

Is all your relevant data on this system portable?  If so you may just want to backup and fresh install RHEL 6.1 variant like [Scientific Linux](https://www.scientificlinux.org/download/)

Comment: Sorry this is a VPS and I have way to much data all over the places.. which would mean be even harder to find what I even need to backup in the first place. I have many other random java servers running in the background.